# how could we redirect to any default page if the requested page is not found or any error occurs in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how could we redirect to any default page if the requested page is not found or any error occurs in asp.net for example in case of error 404...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the customErrors tag within the web.config file.

So, you could have something like this:

```
<configuration>
     ...
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
             <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
        </customErrors>
        ....
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Where Oops.aspx will be the page shown for all HTTP error codes. The inner error tag allows you to specify specific pages for certain error codes. If you don't want that behaviour, just remove the inner tag.

For more info, check out http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my original post to be more useful.

Comment: yeah i have used this code but its not working when uploaded on server, its only working at localhost @grant clements

Answer (score 0):

The customErrors tag in the web.config file is your friend...

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Error.aspx">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can set up a generic catch-all page for generic errors, and then specify pages for individual status codes, allowing you to provide a custom message for 404 errors.

Also note the mode tag - "RemoteOnly" will only display custom errors for remote users, "On" will display custom errors for local users as well.  Use "On" to set-up your error pages, then switch to "RemoteOnly" so you can still see exceptions while developing

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs